# show log for docker build

Tags: git, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a Dockerfile to build on WSL.  `docker build -t name .` resulted in an error with a message like `ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 128: ..` `Check the logs for full command output.`

To check the logs I found the name of the container which was used to build my Dockerfile.  However, `docker logs NAME` returned `Error response from daemon: configured logging driver does not support reading`.  I found that `docker inspect NAME` has `"HostConfig": {"LogConfig": {"Type": "none"}}, "LogPath": ""` entries.  How to fix this and get my logs?  `docker info` outputs `Logging Driver: json-file` and this is desirable.

Comment: Could you tell me the command omitted in the middle? `ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 128: .. Check the logs for full command output.`

Comment: Thanks @myeongkilkim, It is a `git clone -q ..` which is kicked from `pip install -r requirements.txt` with `-e git+https://user:token@github.internal.com/owner/repo.git#someegg` entry. Before `pip install` there is `git config --global http.sslVerify false`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't find and provide the correct answer in time in my personal situation.. However, the problem appears to be a git side issue, not a docker side issue. I have a memory of fixing an issue on the git side of the Error 128 issue. When searching for a keyword, a lot of related materials will be searched.

Comment: Yes, the issue itself must be with git.  I'd like to look into logs for more information....